# Can't create azure cloud cred error : could not find tenant ID , when use UTC time zone

Tags: rancher, azure-sdk

**Rancher Server Setup**

- Rancher version: 2.6.5
- Installation option (Docker install/Helm Chart): helm chart

  - If Helm Chart, Kubernetes Cluster and version (RKE1, RKE2, k3s, EKS, etc): k3s v1.23.6+k3s1

[image]

**cred info is correct by test**

POST /meta/aksCheckCredentials

get response

```
{"error":"could not find tenant ID: Request failed: subscriptions.Client#Get: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: context deadline exceeded"}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the code , I found it  before sending request , rancher will set `context.WithTimeout`

```golang
func FindTenantID(ctx context.Context, env azure.Environment, subscriptionID string) (string, error) {
    goCtx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, findTenantIDTimeout)
    defer cancel()
....
}
```

Finally I solved it by  changing the system time zone to my local zone, default is UTC.

```bash
root@xxx:~# timedatectl
                      Local time: Tue 2022-07-19 03:20:00 UTC
                  Universal time: Tue 2022-07-19 03:20:00 UTC
                        RTC time: Tue 2022-07-19 03:20:01
                       Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

change time zone

```
timedatectl list-timezones | grep -i shang
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Shanghai
```

And you must **reboot**  , just restart rancher is not work.

I don't know this is a bug for rancher  or azure sdk

I also found that ,  the **Environment** field would not be handle by code.